# get value from the drowdown to model in asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, .net-5

I have a .NET 5 application with EntityFramework Core, and I try to link the type of an entity from the drowdown list:

I have a business class

```
public class Bar : IdEntity
{
    public BarType BarType { get; set; }
    
    
public class BarType : IdEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

In order do not use directly `Bar` in the view, I created a DTO (data transfer object, or just a viewModel), like this:

```
public class BarDTO : IdEntityDTO
{
    public int BarTypeId { get; set; }
    public BarType BarType { get; set; }
```

In controller I do:

```
public class BarController : IdEntityController<Bar, BarDTO>
{
    public override async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync()
    {
        var barTypes=await _repository.ListAsync<BarType>();
        ViewBag.BarTypes = barTypes;
        return await base.CreateAsync();
    }
```

In view

```
@model MyApp.Web.ViewModels.BarDTO

<select asp-for="BarTypeId" 
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.BarTypes, 
                                            "Id", "Name"))">
    <option value="">please select</option>
</select>
```

my question is how to link the select user choice with the `BarType` of `Bar` to create a valid `Bar` in the Database with corresponding type id.

Comment: Try to change the type of your field *TypeBar* in your model **Bar** to *BarType*, because currently, your **Bar** model has *TypeBar* of type *TypeBar*, and not *BarType* when your View has drowdopwn for the type of **BarType**, not for *TypeBar*.
**public BarType TypeBar { get; set; }**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem involves the so-called `model binding` in asp.net core. More specifically you want to convert an int `Id` into an instance of `BarType`. The `form` data sent from the client are just string values paired with the corresponding keys. The keys are just like the paths to target the corresponding model property. Because model on the server side may be a complex type with deep properties graph. So the `key` can be a long dot-separated path. In your case your path is just `BarType` which basically targets the wrong corresponding `Id`. The model binder cannot simply convert an `int` to an instance of `BarType`. The correct path is `BarType.Id`. So you can have code like this:

```
<select asp-for="BarType.Id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.BarTypes, "Id", "Name"))">
    <option value="">please select</option>
</select>
```

That would help the model binder create instances of `BarType` automatically with the received `Id`. However we just send the `Id` so the instances of `BarType` have just the `Id` and all the `Name`s are null. `Select` html element can just hold one value mapped with one property and usually that's the key value. In your case actually the model should not need the `BarType.Name` at all. When we deal with selectable data, we just need the selected key/id. With that in mind, we are done with the code above.

If you want to receive the `BarType.Name` as well, I must say that it's wrongly designed. Unless the `BarType.Name` sent from the client can be edited but in this case obviously it's just a constant like the `BarType.Id`. When saving data, the `Id` is what we need to link the entities (establishing the relationship), the other properties don't matter at all and actually can be derived/fetched from the `Id`.

If you still want to receive the `BarType.Name` anyway, you have at least 2 options. The first simple one is to declare a not-mapped property containing both `Id` and `Name`, constructing the computed value in some way so that you can extract each separate value from it. Here is an example:

```
public class BarType : IdEntity
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  //this property should be configured as not-mapped (ignored)
  public string Id_Name {
     get {
        if(_id_Name == null){
            _id_Name = $"{Id}_{Name}";
        }
        return _id_Name;
     }
     set {
        _id_Name = value;
     }
  }
  string _id_Name;
  
  //a method to parse back the Id & Name
  public BarType ParseIdName(){
      if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id_Name)){
          var parts = Id_Name.Split(new[] {'_'}, 2);
          Id = int.TryParse(parts[0], out var id) ? id : 0;
          Name = parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] : null;
      }
      return this;
  }
}
```

Now instead of using `Id` for the selected value, you use `Id_Name`:

```
<select asp-for="BarType.Id_Name" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.BarTypes, "Id_Name", "Name"))">
        <option value="">please select</option>
</select>
```

Note that before actually using the bound `BarType` available from the model in the controller action, you need to manually call the method `BarType.ParseIdName`like this:

```
public override Task<IActionResult> Create(Bar entity) 
{
    entity.BarType?.ParseIdName();
    //the entity is ready now ...
    //...
    return base.Create(entity);
}
```

The first option is simple but a bit tricky and I would not personally use it. The more standard way to do it is using the second option with a custom `IModelBinder`. This targets the model type `BarType` and resolves an `Id` into an instance of `BarType`. This resolution process should be fast.

```
public class BarTypeModelBinder : IModelBinder {
     public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var fieldValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.FieldName).FirstValue;
        //here we just instantiate an instance of BarType with Id but without Name
        if(int.TryParse(fieldValue, out var id)){
          bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Succeed(new BarType { Id = id });
        }
        else {
          bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
        }         
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

You should use that model binder like this:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(BarTypeModelBinder))]
public class BarType : IdEntity
{
   //...
}
```

That's almost done. Now talk about how you resolve instance of `BarType` from just its `Id`. As I said, usually we just need the `Id` so just create an instance of `BarType` containing just Id (as the code above does) is enough. That's of course very fast. If you need the `Name` as well, you may have to resolve the instance of `BarType` using some service. Because it's required to be fast, you really need some kind of `in-memory` lookup (or cached data). Suppose you have a service to resolve a `BarType` instance from its `Id` like this:

```
public interface IBarTypeService {
   BarType GetBarType(int id);
}
```

You can use that service in the `BarTypeModelBinder` like this:

```
if(int.TryParse(fieldValue, out var id)){
   var barType = _barTypeService.GetBarType(id);
   bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Succeed(barType);
}
else {
   bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
}
```

The second option may be a bit complicated for beginners (because it involves a nice `IBarTypeService` with support of caching or at least a nice way to feed it with some in-memory data lookup) but really it's the standard way to go. Once you become familiar with that logic, it just feels normal.

Comment: in order do not mess business and the view logic I created a DTO Object, having both `BarTypeId` and `BarType` properties. I use AutoMapper to map business to DTO classes

Comment: @Serge I'm not sure what you mean but the problem of `model binding` does not matter how you design the view models (or dtos). It just cares about the view model you use in the action method and the values you post from the client. So its job is fill the received data into the view model. In this case I understand that your view model is `Bar` (exposing a `BarType` property) exactly as what you posted. If you have something difficult to apply the solutions I introduced, please update your question with your real view models so that I may help.

Comment: I updated the OP to reflect the changes I made

Comment: also available in discord https://discord.gg/PNMq3pBSUe

Comment: @Serge really I hoped that you would append your updated content, not overwrite the old content which may make almost what I answered become non-sense. For what you updated, I see that `CreateAsync` does not accept any argument, so how would you get the data posted from the client? That's important to see what's the actual problem.

Comment: @Serge as I understand, as before, you have `Bar`, now you have `BarDTO` instead. So basically it's not much difference, you have the `BarTypeId` populated, you then can create the corresponding instance of `BarType` (with that id) to set for the `BarType` property. If you read my solutions carefully, you will find out how to deal with whatever view model you have. The key point here is you can just bind the selected id to `BarTypeId`. If you want a `Bar` instance, you need to create that manually (because only the DTO model can be auto-created as the result of model binding).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228082/discussion-between-serge-and-king-king).